# MongoDB should i make another collection or should i embed it

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, database-design, schema

I am making a music app fron node js and i choosed mongodb as database for it. I know basic syntax for mongodb operations but i am new to schema designs. I havent learnt any database software before mongoDB.

So in this app, every time the user likes a song, i store all the important data of that song in seperate collection called `tracker` and `liked` so it will be easier to make recommendation algorithm. The `users` collection schema is like this:

```js
{
  uid: Unique Custom Ids,
  private: {
     email: email,
     phone: number,
  },
  public: {
    profile: {
      info: {
         bio: String,
         name: String,
         username: String
      },
      src: {
        pfpSrc: Url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my tracker collections schema looks like:

```js
{
  uid: custom uid,
  byLiked: {
    genre: {
      genreName: "No of time user liked this genre"
    },
    tags: {
      tag: "No of time user liked this tag"
    }
  },
    byPlays: {
    genre: {
      genreName: "No of time user liked this genre"
    },
    tags: {
      tag: "No of time user liked this tag"
    }
  }
}
```

the `liked` collection schema looks like this:

```js
{
  uid: "custom uid",
  tracks: [
    {song_id: "custom song id"},
    ...
  ]
}
```

Should i do in this way or embed all these collection in documents of `users` collection?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

There is basically 3 criterias, on which you can decide, whether you should embed or reference the related entity.

This criterias are:

- relationship type,
- data access patterns (how often data is read and written),
- data closeness (how "much" is the data related, how we want to query)

When evaluate, you should combine all this three criterias.

Choose embedding if:

- the relationship is one to few or one to many (not soo many)
- data is mostly read and doesn't change quickly
- datasets really belong together

Choose referencing if:

- the relationship is one to many, one to ton (new term in document based dbs), many to many
- data is updated a lot
- both datasets need to be queried frequently on their own

Looking over your scenario, I highly recommend to choose referencing.

Comment: If the answer was satisfied to you, then please mark it as accepted. Thank you.