# MongoDB inventory system: one document per item or an Array

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, database-design

I'm making an inventory system and I am stuck on a question which might have a huge difference in the future

Should I store the items of the inventories as 1 document per player with an Array containing each item
Or should I store each item of a player inventory in a single document?

I want to be safe for future so I'm assuming there could be up to 100 000 players each having up to a 100 items in their inventories. Maybe more but not insane amounts.

Also I will retrieve all the items from a player inventory quite some times

An item looks like this:

```
> {
>     "_id": {
>         "$oid": "60bb4a3585cac232f479a9f5"
>     },
>     "itemID": "wooden_sword",
>     "type": "weapon",
>     "attack": 5,
>     "enchantements": {}
> }
```

Comment: It depends on what the inventory contains.

Comment: I updated my post to include what a item looks like

Comment: Please look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67500840/mongodb-should-i-make-another-collection-or-should-i-embed-it/67524039#67524039